# Toast Message Not Shown when Android API is 31 or Above

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I updated my Android app to API 31 recently because of the new policy about "Target API level requirements for Google Play apps" here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en

Since I update the API to 31, I found that the Toast message is not shown when I turn off my notification.

Is there any way to show Toast messages when I turn off the notification on my phone or my app?

I know that the Toast message works correctly when I turn on my notification on my phone/app.

But I still want to figure out the solution to solve this problem.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you share some piece of code to understand you need.. without I can’t figure out anything…

Comment: If `Toast` class behaves like this, you may use `SnackBar` from Google as a replacement.

Comment: `SnackBar` relies on activity to show so it is more like a dialog. It will not be disabled by system setting (just my believe I am not sure though). Though this has a limitation that your activity must in foreground in order to show the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just further reply your question here.

Searching `Toast` logic from the AOSP source code, it will check the notification enabled or not to decide whether to show the `Toast`.

**AOSP Website REF:**
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java Line: 3330

---

So if you have the ability to deploy the ROM by yourself, you can definitely change the AOSP code there.

And if you are just a normal app developer, you shall follow the strict rules defined.

Either replace your `Toast` with other implementation (e.g., `SnackBar`) or show a warning when you determine users have disabled the feature.

Comment: Thank you sir.
Since I'm not trying to deploy ROM by my self, I'll try to replace the Toast function to SnackBar or other function.
Again, thanks to your reply.